# what is gotk notation/symbol means in the fluxcd

Tags: kubernetes, fluxcd, k8s-rolebinding

recently I saw a usage of using flux cd to do deployment in k8s:

```
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: gotk:xxxx:reconciler
```

but I really don't understand what gotk:xxxx:reconciler means and what this User refers to. I also cannot find any documentation about it? Anyone fluxcd expert?

Answer (score 1):

GoTK stands for "**GitOps Toolkit**" in the Flux context.

It's a collection of specialized tools, controllers, APIs, and reusable Go packages designed to support GitOps practices.

Source: https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/

> **GitOps Toolkit components**
>
> Flux is constructed with the GitOps Toolkit components, which is a set
> of
>
> - specialized tools and Flux Controllers
> - composable APIs
> - reusable Go packages for GitOps under the fluxcd GitHub organisation